# Title of each line should look different in android 4.1 inbox style notification?

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean

[image: Android (4.1) Inbox Style Notification]

I'm wondering how gmail app is able to set the title of each line in jellybean inbox style notification differently e.g here "(Google+), Google Play, Stack Exchange" etc have brighter color text comparing to their individual details. Any clue ?

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#BigNotify

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`addLine()` on `InboxStyle` takes a `CharSequence`. Hence, you can use a `SpannedString` instead of a regular `String`, where the `SpannedString` contains inline markup rules. A convenient (if a bit slow) way to accomplish this is to use `Html.fromHtml()` to convert simple HTML markup into a suitable `CharSequence`.

Answer (score 2):

Able to resolve this after getting hint from CommonsWare. Thanks a lot.
Finally method looks like this

```
private SpannableString getFormattedString(String contact, String lastMessage)
{
    String boldContact = "<b>" + contact + "</b>";
    return new SpannableString(Html.fromHtml(boldContact + " " + lastMessage));
}
```